# Is the only `FlippyFloppyMorphism` `const mempty`?

Tags: haskell, monoids, typeclass-laws

In Haskell, we have the interesting fact that any type constructor `f :: * -> *` which is simultaneously a `Functor` and a `Contravariant` is phantom in its type parameter:

```
phantom :: (Functor f, Contravariant f) => f x -> f y
```

Another way to put this is that every type constructor that is simultaneously a `Functor`s and a `Contravariant` is naturally isomorphic to `Const x`, for some `x`.

This implies that the "only" way (up to isomorphism) to instantiate the class:

```
class FlippyFloppyFunctor f
  where
  ffmap :: Either (y -> x) (x -> y) -> f x -> f y
```

so that it obeys the functor laws:

```
ffmap (Left id)       = id
ffmap (Right id)      = id
ffmap (Left  (g . f)) = ffmap (Left f)  . ffmap (Left g)
ffmap (Right (f . g)) = ffmap (Right f) . ffmap (Right g)
```

is:

```
weirdmap :: Either (y -> x) (x -> y) -> Const r x -> Const r y
weirdmap = const $ \(Const x) -> Const x
```

i.e. modulo newtypes, `const id`.

I find it difficult to understand why this is the only function of its type that satisfies the constraints, although I can sort of understand various informal arguments involving `absurd :: Void -> a`/`discard :: a -> ()` as to why the existence of such a map implies the functor "is phantom" in its type parameter.

To understand it better, I tried to simplify the problem. Instead of thinking about `FlippyFloppyFunctor`, let's think about:

```
class (Monoid a, Monoid b) => FlippyFloppyMorphism a b
  where
  ffmorph :: Either a a -> b
```

with analogous laws:

```
ffmorph (Left mempty)    = mempty
ffmorph (Right mempty)   = mempty
ffmorph (Left  (y <> x)) = ffmorph (Left x)  <> ffmorph (Left y)
ffmorph (Right (x <> y)) = ffmorph (Right x) <> ffmorph (Right y)
```

Assuming that `a` and `b` [are non-commutative monoids](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64059932/1726343), is it still true that the only lawful implementation of `FlippyFloppyMorphism` is `const mempty`? Is it still possible to explain why the morphism must be "phantom" in the input monoids, without having a `Void` or a `()` to refer to?

Comment: What exactly is `ExistsF`? I can’t seem to find it with Hoogle.

Comment: @bradrn sorry, that's an artifact of an earlier draft, let me get rid of it. (done)

Comment: I’ve read this through a couple of times now, but I’m not sure I understand how `FlippyFloppyMorphism` is related to `FlippyFloppyFunctor`… could you give an example of a `FlippyFloppyMorphism` instance? That might help a bit.

Comment: @bradrn That's precisely the question. The only lawful instance I can think of is `ffmorph = const mempty`. Can you think of any others, or an argument as to why none should exist? I can't think of any, but at the same time I'm unable to formulate an argument as to why none should exist.

Comment: The relationship between `FlippyFloppyFunctor` and `FlippyFloppyMorphism` is a little more apparent if you put their laws side by side and diff them.

Comment: Ah yes, I see the relationship now… the `ffmorph` laws are just the `ffmap` laws with `(.)` replaced by `(<>)`. (Not sure why I didn’t see that before!)

Comment: An idea… it appears that `FlippyFloppyMorphism` admits an instance `Monoid a => FlippyFloppyMorphism a a` for any `a`. Does this have any counterpart in `FlippyFloppyFunctor`?

Comment: @bradrn Sorry, I just realized I screwed up again in the question and flipped _twice_, but using `Dual` as well as using `y <> x`. I just fixed it, thought i'd call it out in case you were building on top of the error.

Comment: Ah, thanks for correcting that! (Luckily I hadn’t built anything on top of it… maybe I’ll do some more exploring now that that’s fixed.)

Comment: @bradrn Regarding your question, since `FlippyFloppyMorphism` admits an instance for any commutative monoid, a counterpart in `FlippyFloppyFunctor` might be to say that if we restrict `->` to mean functions that are part of an isomorphism, we have as many non-phantom `FlippyFloppyFunctor`s as we have invariant functors.

Comment: No, actually I was wrong when I asked that question — I was using the former incorrect formulation in terms of `Dual` rather than the corrected one.

Comment: @bradrn I understand that, but the premise of the question is close enough to being correct that we can answer it: while there isn't an instance for every monoid, there is an instance for every commutative monoid, and we can find an analog for this fact in functor case.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that the answer in the general case is "no", because monoids can be commutative.

If the monoid is commutative, then `Dual a` is the same monoid as `a`, and `Either a a` is the same as `a`, and hence we just degenerate to asking whether `ffmorph` is the only monoid homomorphism `a -> b`. The answer is "no".

For example, for the commutative monoid of addition, we have `replicate 'a' :: Either (Sum Int) (Sum Int) -> String`, where:

```
replicateA (Left  0) = ""
replicateA (Right 0) = ""
replicateA (Left  (y + x)) = replicateA (Left x) ++ replicateA (Left y)
replicateA (Right (x + y)) = replicateA (Left x) ++ replicateA (Left y)
```

However, I think it might be the case that for _non_commutative monoids, the only possible implementation is `const mempty` (which I still don't have a proof for).

Comment: I think this answer may be in need of correction given the edit removing `Dual` from the question.

Comment: @bradrn I think the answer is correct, I realized in the process of writing it that I'd made the mistake in the question. The idea is that we either need to flip the order of composition/append in `whatever (Left (y <> x))`, or we need to flip `<>` itself, using a newtype. I did *both* in the question, which essentially resulted in the `Left` case being the same as the `Right` case.

Comment: @bradrn Ah, nevermind, you're right. I did have a stray reference to `Dual` in the answer. Thanks!

Comment: Yep, that ‘stray reference’ is what I was talking about.